# Displaying data from sessionStorage in a Table-Solution Found

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, sessionstorage

I am setting up a ordering site so that when an item is added to the basket it gets stored in sessionStorage. This is then recalled and displayed in a table for the customer to see. Currently I am storing my information and displaying a table but all the values are coming up undefined. Can anyone help me see what is wrong I believe it to be my toTable function but am unsure how. Here is the code I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am still learning how to fully use Javascript.

HTML call

```
var basket = sessionStorage.bask;
    if(basket){
        basket=JSON.parse(basket);
        if(_.size(basket)) content = toTable(basket);
```

Javascript functions

```
function Basket(){
    var css = 'input#size[name="toy"]:checked';
    var input = document.querySelector(css);    
    var size = input.value==='1'?'small':'large';
    var price = Number(input.getAttribute('data-price'));
    var orderline = [this.name,size,price];
    addToBasket(orderline);
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="order" + sessionStorage.bask;

    }

    function addToBasket(item){
        var basket=sessionStorage.bask;
        if(basket){
        basket=JSON.parse(basket);
    }else{
        basket=new Object();
    }
        var name = nextName(basket);
        basket[name]=item;
        sessionStorage.bask=JSON.stringify(basket,null,'\t');
      }

    function toTable(basket){
         var count = 0;
         var str = '<table id="basket" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">';
    for (var key in basket){
             str+= '<tr id="body" class="">';
             str+= '<td>'+basket[key].size+'</td>';
             str+= '<td>'+basket[key].name+'</td>';
             str+= '<td>&pound;'+basket[key].price+'</td></tr>';
         }

         str+= '<tr><td colspan="3"> Total Price&pound;'+getPrice(basket).toFixed(2)+'</td></tr>';
         return str+'<table/>';
     }
```

Comment: Are you getting the expected number of rows in your table? At the top of `toTable` add `console.log (JSON.stringify (basket));` and carefully check  what is displayed on the console (or post it here).

Comment: I was getting the expected number of rows. Since posting this question I figured out where I was going wrong in the toTable function instead of size, name and price I needed [0], [1] and [2]. Thank you for you're reply.

Comment: Great that you figured it out. In future please add a comment or edit your question with the solution you found.